# What is the value for the plasmon frequency of intrinsic $\rm Si$?

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, plasmon

I found some values for the plasma frequency $\omega_p$ of doped $\rm Si$, but not for intrinsic Si. Because of this, I tried to calculate it with

$$
\omega_p^2 = \frac{ne^2}{m_\text{eff}\ \epsilon_0\epsilon_r}
$$

My result doesn't really make sense, is my formula wrong or something else? I only used SI units.

Also, is the plasmon energy $E_p=\hbar\omega_p$ the same plasmon energy that can be found in EELS for the bulk plasmon peak?

Comment: Hi johcdi, please see [how to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). For now I've edited your question for you.

Comment: Is not instrinsic Si a gapped semiconductor?  If so, the carrier density is  $n=0$ at low temperatures, and $\propto \exp\{ -E_{\rm gap}/kT\}$ at finite temperatures. Did you consider that?

Comment: @mikestone I used room temperature, so $n=10^{10}cm^{-1}$. Specifically I used: intrinsic carrier concentration $n=10^{10} \cdot 10^6 m^{-1}$, 
elementary charge $1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}$ C, 
effective mass $m_{eff}=0.26 \cdot m_0$ (mass of electron $m_0=9.1 \cdot10^{-31} $kg),
vacuum permittivity $\epsilon_0=8.85 \cdot 10^{-12}$ F/m and
relative permittivity $\epsilon_r=11,68$.

Comment: It should be $n=10^{10} {\rm cm}^{-3}$ I asume that the $ {\rm cm}^{-1}$ is a typo ;).  That makes sense, what is wrong with your plasma frequency answer?

Comment: Yes it was a typo thanks :) I get $\lambda_{plasmon} = 0.58$m which seems fairly high. I do not have any value to compare it too though, which is why my title question is what the value should be.

Comment: @jochdi - well, if you have some values for doped silicon, do they agree with the formula (which is the right formula presuming you are handling the epsilon(s) properly).